# Why does GCC order integers on the stack in this way?

Tags: c++, gcc, memory, stack

There are some existing questions about GCC ordering of variables on the stack. However, those usually involve intermixed variables and arrays, and this is not that. I'm working with the GCC 9.2.0 64-bit release, with no special flags on. If I do this:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int a = 15, b = 30, c = 45, d = 60;
//  std::cout << &a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Then the memory layout is seen as in the disassembly here:

```
   0x000000000040156d <+13>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0xf
   0x0000000000401574 <+20>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],0x1e
   0x000000000040157b <+27>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0xc],0x2d
   0x0000000000401582 <+34>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],0x3c
```

So: The four variables are in order at offsets 0x04, 0x08, 0x0C, 0x10 from the RBP; that is, sequenced in the same order they were declared. This is consistent and deterministic; I can re-compile, add other lines of code (random printing statements, other later variables, etc.) and the layout remains the same.

However, as soon as I include a line that touches an address or pointer, then the layout changes. For example, this:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int a = 15, b = 30, c = 45, d = 60;
    std::cout << &a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Produces this:

```
   0x000000000040156d <+13>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],0xf
   0x0000000000401574 <+20>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x1e
   0x000000000040157b <+27>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],0x2d
   0x0000000000401582 <+34>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0xc],0x3c
```

So: A scrambled-up layout with the variables at offsets now respectively at 0x10, 0x04, 0x08, 0x0C. Again, this is consistent with any re-compiles, most random code I think to add, etc.

However, if I just touch a different address like so:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int a = 15, b = 30, c = 45, d = 60;
    std::cout << &b << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Then the variables get ordered like this:

```
   0x000000000040156d <+13>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0xf
   0x0000000000401574 <+20>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],0x1e
   0x000000000040157b <+27>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],0x2d
   0x0000000000401582 <+34>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0xc],0x3c
```

That is, a different sequence at offsets 0x04, 0x10, 0x08, 0x0C. Once again, this is consistent as far as I can tell with recompilations and code changes, excepting if I refer to some other address in the code.

If I didn't know any better, it would seem like the integer variables are placed in declaration order, unless the code does any manipulation with addressing, at which point it starts scrambling them up in some deterministic way.

Some responses that will **not** satisfy this question are as follows:

- "The behavior is undefined in the C++ standard" -- I'm not asking about the C++ standard, I'm asking specifically about how this GCC compiler makes its decision on layout.
- "The compiler can do whatever it wants" -- Does not answer how the compiler decides on what it "wants" in this specific, consistent case.

**Why does the GCC compiler layout integer variables in this way?**

**What explains the consistent re-ordering seen here?**

**Edit:** I guess on closer inspection, the variable whose address I touch is always placed in `[rbp-0x10]`, and then the other ones are put in declaration order sequence after that. Why would that be beneficial? Note that printing the *values* of any of these variables don't seem to trigger the same re-ordering, from what I can tell.

Comment: What about compiling with `-O0`? Seems plausible it's just part of some optimization that doesn't actually make any difference in this specific case.

Comment: @super With optimizations, a compiler usually does not allocate variables that are not used: https://godbolt.org/z/dPq5Ks5Wd.

Comment: I assume that gcc place the variable which is used on the most alligned address, which could improve access speed, cache usage or something like that.

Comment: Why does the order of local variables in your call frame matter to you? The C standard [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) don't mention them, and you should not care! Any compiler is allowed to use CPU registers for variables! Your question is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), and you should explain in written English why do you care about variables orders and layout

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I refer you to the part of the question listing, "Some responses that will **not** satisfy this question"

Comment: That does not explain "why does the order of local variables matter to you". For example, your code might be compiled by a GCC with a plugin, or by another version of GCC, or of Clang, which order local variables differently. You probably have a reason to ask your question, and it is worth explaining that reason

Answer (score -1):

You should compile your `daniel.cc` C++ code with `g++ -O -fverbose-asm -daniel.cc -S -o daniel.s` and look into the generated assembler code `daniel.s`

For your first example, a lot of constants and slots in your [call frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#CALL-FRAME) have disappeared, since optimized:

```
         .text
         .globl  main
         .type   main, @function
 main:
 .LFB1644:
         .cfi_startproc
         endbr64 
         subq    $24, %rsp       #,
         .cfi_def_cfa_offset 32
 # daniel.cc:2: int main() {
         movq    %fs:40, %rax    # MEM[(<address-space-1> long unsigned int *)40B], tmp89
         movq    %rax, 8(%rsp)   # tmp89, D.41631
         xorl    %eax, %eax      # tmp89
 # daniel.cc:3:     int a = 15, b = 30, c = 45, d = 60;
         movl    $15, 4(%rsp)    #, a
 # /usr/include/c++/10/ostream:246:       { return _M_insert(__p); }
         leaq    4(%rsp), %rsi   #, tmp85
         leaq    _ZSt4cout(%rip), %rdi   #,
         call    _ZNSo9_M_insertIPKvEERSoT_@PLT  #
         movq    %rax, %rdi      # tmp88, _4
 # /usr/include/c++/10/ostream:113:      return __pf(*this);
         call    _ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_@PLT  #
 # daniel.cc:6: }
         movq    8(%rsp), %rax   # D.41631, tmp90
         subq    %fs:40, %rax    # MEM[(<address-space-1> long unsigned int *)40B], tmp90
         jne     .L4     #,
         movl    $0, %eax        #,
         addq    $24, %rsp       #,
         .cfi_remember_state
         .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
         ret     
 .L4:
         .cfi_restore_state
         call    __stack_chk_fail@PLT    #
         .cfi_endproc
 .LFE1644:
         .size   main, .-main
         .type   _GLOBAL__sub_I_main, @function
```

If for whatever reason you really require your call frame to contain slots in a known order, you need to use a `struct` as an automatic variable (and that approach is portable to other C++ compilers).

If you need to understand why GCC has compiled your code the way it did, **download the source code of GCC**, read the [documentation of GCC internals](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/), study it (it is free software).

You should be interested by [GCC developer options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Developer-Options.html#Developer-Options), they dump a lot of things regarding the internal state of the compiler.

Once you understood a bit what GCC actually does, subscribe to some GCC mailing list (e.g. [`gcc@gcc.gnu.org`](https://gcc.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/gcc)) and ask questions there. Alternatively, code your [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) to improve its behavior, change the organization of the call frame, add dumping routines.

If you need to understand or improve GCC, budget several months of full time work, and read the [Dragon book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) before.

Comment: I guess I don't see the point of the suggestion to take my un-optimized assembly, which shows the variables I'm investigating, and optimizing them out of the picture.